# fetching GDataFeedPhotoAlbum returns wrong object type

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, gdata-api, picasa

I'm trying to implement fetching an picasa web album on iphone, have downloaded the code and example from google.code but have run into a problem where fetching an album feed returns me feed with wrong object types - **GDataEntryBase** instead of **GDataEntryPhoto**.

Here's the code I'm using:

First I'm calling this to get all my albums:

```
- (void)fetchAllAlbums 
{
    NSLog(@"Fetching all albums");

    //request albums
    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;    
    NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGooglePhotos photoFeedURLForUserID:myemail
                                                             albumID:nil
                                                           albumName:nil
                                                             photoID:nil
                                                                kind:nil
                                                              access:nil];
    ticket = [_GooglePhotoService fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                                          delegate:self
                                 didFinishSelector:@selector(albumListFetchTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
    [self set_AlbumFetchTicket: ticket];
}
```

Now, in the callback I call to get all the photos of each returned album:

```
- (void)albumListFetchTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
            finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedPhotoUser *)feed
                       error:(NSError *)error 
{
    [self set_UserAlbumFeed: feed];
    [self set_AlbumFetchError:error];
    [self set_AlbumFetchTicket:nil];

    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Got albums!");

        for (GDataEntryPhotoAlbum * albumEntry in _UserAlbumFeed)
        {
            NSLog(@"Album Title: %@", [[albumEntry title] stringValue]);
            {
                NSLog(@"Fetching photos!");

                [self set_AlbumPhotosFeed:nil];
                [self set_PhotosFetchError:nil];
                [self set_PhotosFetchTicket:nil];

                GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
                ticket = [_GooglePhotoService fetchFeedWithURL: [[albumEntry feedLink] URL]
                                                      delegate: self
                                             didFinishSelector: @selector(photosTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];

                [self set_PhotosFetchTicket:ticket];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the callback for each album photo feed fetch:

```
// photo list fetch callback
- (void)photosTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
    finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedPhotoAlbum *)feed
               error:(NSError *)error 
{
    //tell me what class you are
    NSLog(@"Feed class: %@", NSStringFromClass([feed class]));

    [self set_AlbumPhotosFeed:   feed];
    [self set_PhotosFetchError:  error];
    [self set_PhotosFetchTicket: ticket];

    if (error == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Got Photos!");

        for (GDataEntryPhoto * photo in feed)
        {
            NSLog(@"Title: %@", [[photo title] stringValue]);

            //tell me what class you are
            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([photo class]));

            //NSArray * thumbnails = [[photo mediaGroup] mediaThumbnails];
            //NSLog(@"thumbnails count: %d", [thumbnails count]);
            //NSLog(@"Photo thumnail url: %@", [[thumbnails objectAtIndex:0] URLString]);
        }            
    }
}
```

The trouble is that the entries in the feed in the last callback are not of type GDataEntryPhoto, just the base GDataEntryBase - and so trying to access their thumbnail urls will crash the app.
The code is copied from google's cocoa (non-touch) example, and there it works - the feed returned is populated with the GDateEntryPhoto objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-ObjC -all_load` to **Other Linker Flags** in your xcodeproject, then add `SystemConfiguration.framework`, `CFNetwork.framework` and `Security.framework` to **Build Phases** -> **Link Library With Binaries**.

Comment: Yes, because it causes everything in the libraries to be loaded by the linker, which causes new dependencies.  Add the frameworks/libs that have the newly referenced symbols, and it will work.